# Как отправить видеозапись на сервер

Tags: java, android, http

Мне никогда не приходилось отправлять медиафайлы на сервер. Обычные текстовые данные отправлял так:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Application.TEST_API + Application.TEST_API_IDENTIFIER);

httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "save_profiles_result"));
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profiles", jsonProfiles));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Но у меня щас совсем другая задача, никак не могу понять как мне вставить

```
String outputpath = VideoRecordConfig.getOutputMediaFile(
            VideoRecordConfig.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).getAbsolutePath();
```

Типа так, только тут `outputpath` просто название файла

```
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("video", outputpath ));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставить мне видео в `ValuePairs`? Может это кому то покажется глупым вопросом, но я совсем не шарю в медиафайлах!

Answer (score -1):

При передаче бинарных данных через HTTP при помощи POST запроса обычно используется [multipart](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data).

Еще бы порекомендовал для сообщения с сервером использовать библиотеку [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.